# Launch python from specific exe in PHP

Tags: php, python, cmd

I've a php file for launch my python file with default version (2.7):

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    system("cmd /c D:\web\folder\easypy.py");
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

But I developped a python file more strong who work with other python (3.5). So I need to use the exe of the version 3.5 in my php.

I tried this :

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    system("cmd /c D:\web\folder\strongpy.py D:\folder1\folder2\python35\python.exe");
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

But it not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

system in php looks like this:

```
system("command", $retval); //retval is optional
```

command in your case is:

```
 "cmd /c D:/folder1/folder2/python35/python.exe D:/web/folder/strongpy.py"
```

the final php code looks like this:

```
system("cmd /c D:/folder1/folder2/python35/python.exe D:/web/folder/strongpy.py");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't work. If I try this directly in CMD, it works if I choose directory of `strongpy.py`. It's possible problem comme from an empty `change directory` option ?

Comment: the answer is less complicate :) use / slasher and not \ (answer edited)

Comment: Oh yes, excuse me, I'm confused. But I've an other problem the current directory is the directory of the PHP file. How can I change current directory ? I try this `cmd cd /d C:\` but it doesn't work...

Comment: system("cmd /c c:");

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I nresume I've that : `system("cmd /c C: /c c:/(...)/python.exe c:/(...)/strongpy.py` . I tried with cd like `system("cmd cd /c C: (...)` but nothing work...

Comment: write every command separately like this:
system("cmd /c c:"); 
system("cmd /c c:/(...)/python.exe c:/(...)/strongpy.py");

Comment: Okay my code doesn't work, and my complete code like that : `system("cmd /c D:/folder/python"); system("cmd /c C:/folder/python/python.exe D:/folder/python/strongpy.py");`. If I launch directly in CMD with `CD D:/folder/python` etc... all it work. If I launch this python directly with IDLE interface of Python It works. I don't understand at all why can I don't launch it with PHP.

Comment: system("cmd /c cd /d D:/folder/python"); 
system("cmd /c C:/folder/python/python.exe D:/folder/python/strongpy.py");
cmd /c = run command line then you have to write command line command

Comment: I understand your explication but it not work too...I've a `print()` of the current directory in my python code and when I launch my PHP I've this response : `<pre>D:\web\site_sig_cclo\site_3_administration\script\python
</pre>` So with this we can see this treatment launch my python code but the result of this python code is....nothing, and if I launch this python code directyle it works !

Comment: are you using apache? (xamp, wamp, whatever) look into error.log file, it might help

Comment: I find the answer ! I tested my code on IDLE Python and not from CMD. I didn't know but it does'nt work with the same process.